# How can I compute the sum of the levels in a BST

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I've been scratching my head for a few hours and can't figure this out. I need to create a method that "computes the sum of the levels of the nodes in the tree," however my method keeps returning 0.

I've stepped through it several times with the debugger and it starts out okay but when it reaches the bottom of the method it returns lvl and resets back to 0.

If anyone can help me understand why this is happening I would appreciate it. Thanks

```
    public int sumOfLevels() {
    return sumOfLevels(_root, 0);
}

private int sumOfLevels(Node node, int lvl) {
    if (node == null)
        return lvl;
    sumOfLevels(node.right, lvl);
    lvl += findLevel(node.data);
    sumOfLevels(node.left, lvl);

    return lvl;
}
```

Comment: As with most tree problems, you want to approach it recursively. Suppose you have a node and you know the sums of levels within each of its children, and you know its level. How would you calculate the total sum of levels within that node?

Comment: I guess I'm struggling with this BST stuff. It would be something like level of parent + level sum child left + level sum child right?

Comment: 1. Please add a sample tree with the expected answer. 2. Please add the `findLevel()` method in your question.

Comment: It's immediately suspicious that `sumOfLevels` computes the `sumOfLevels` of a node's children and then throws those results away.  Should they not have been included in some sum, somewhere?

Comment: Yes, @CollinThompson, exactly.  The `sumOfLevels` of a node is going to be that node's own level **plus** the `sumOfLevels` of its left child **plus** the sumOfLevels of its right child.  Your code seems to be missing the "plus" part of "_plus_ the `sumOfLevels` of the right/left child"...

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it worked out by doing         
`lvl += sumOfLevels(node.right, lvl) +
                findLevel(node.data) +
                sumOfLevels(node.left, lvl);`

I appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `findLevel()` function that figures out the level on every recursive call, that's very inefficient. Just pass on the current level as an argument. Like this:

```
private int sumOfLevels(Node node, int currentlvl) {
    if (node == null)
        return 0;
    else {
        int sum = currentlvl;
        sum += sumOfLevels(node.right, currentlvl + 1);
        sum += sumOfLevels(node.left, currentlvl + 1);
        return sum;
    }
}
```